# iPhone,FMDatabase : executeQuery not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, fmdb

Below is the code i am using:

```
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [[DataBaseHelper sharedManager] queue];
[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"select * from EVENT where ESTATUS='unread' and HIT_ATTEMPTS < 5 "];

if([results next])
{
   [results close];

   @try {
           BOOL success=FALSE;
           NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into EVENT (EDATA, ESTATUS ,EUSER) values('%@','%@','%@')",@"google.com",@"unread",@"xyz"];

           success = [db executeUpdate:query];
           NSLog(@"create edata row, %d:%@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
        }

   @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception");
   }
```

In the above code 
success = [db executeUpdate:query]; is not working. I have tried placing breakpoints. After this line of code all exits. None of the logs get printed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using a try and Catch, anywayz follow the steps it will surely work

**Creating A Database**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
```

**Opening The Database And Creating Tables(optional)**

```
[database open];
//optional
[database executeUpdate:@"create table user(name text primary key, age int)"];
```

**Querying The Database**

```
FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:@"select * from user"];
while([results next]) {
    NSString *name = [results stringForColumn:@"name"];
    NSInteger age  = [results intForColumn:@"age"];        
    NSLog(@"User: %@ - %d",name, age);
}
[database close];
```

Comment: With out try catch also same issue persists

Comment: @TechFanatic  have you tried the easy way, i have mentioned??